Splitting an array in Julia
I have an array that I wish to split using " " as the delimiter. I am using the Base.split function, but there seems to be an error coming up. The array in question (poly) is as follows:
Any["-39.242054 -62.0887375 -39.9433022 -62.5120087 -40.4574928 -61.6601334 -39.7562447 -61.2368622 -39.242054 -62.0887375"]

The code is as follows:
coords = split(poly, " ")

The error is:
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching split(::Vector{Any}, ::String)

I suppose I cannot use this on the data structure type of poly. What are other methods which I can check out?

Split only the first element of the array, that is a String. More in general, check your code for how you ended up with an array of a single string instead of directly a string.

Have also a look at using DelimitedFiles and readdlm as this might be most convenient when reading the data you now try to process.

split works on Strings, not on Arrays:
julia> poly = "-39.242054 -62.0887375 -39.9433022 -62.5120087 -40.4574928 -61.6601334 -39.7562447 -61.2368622 -39.242054 -62.0887375"
"-39.242054 -62.0887375 -39.9433022 -62.5120087 -40.4574928 -61.6601334 -39.7562447 -61.2368622 -39.242054 -62.0887375"

julia> split(poly, " ")
10-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
 "-39.242054"
 "-62.0887375"
 "-39.9433022"
 "-62.5120087"
 "-40.4574928"
 "-61.6601334"
 "-39.7562447"
 "-61.2368622"
 "-39.242054"
 "-62.0887375"

